# Find missing/ deleted rows in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table which stores full extracts from source. I want to track id which are missing in the full extracts and store it in the target table (desired output) format. can you advise on sql.

**source table**

```
id  source_extract_date 

1   1/1/2001  
2   1/1/2001  
3   1/1/2001
4   1/1/2001

1   2/1/2001   
3   2/1/2001
4   2/1/2001

1   3/1/2001   
3   3/1/2001
4   3/1/2001

1   4/1/2001   
3   4/1/2001
2   4/1/2001

1   5/1/2001   
3   5/1/2001
2   5/1/2001
```

**target table (desired output)**

```
id    effective_from    is_deleted
1       1/1/2001            false
2       1/1/2001            false
3       1/1/2001            false
4       1/1/2001            false
2       2/1/2001            true
4       4/1/2001            true
2       4/1/2001            false
```

Comment: Please explain the logic you used to come up with the desired result.

Comment: You tagged three different databases (SQL Server, Postgres, Snowflake). Please choose one.

Comment: Why isn't 5/1/2001 not included in the desired output?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  The logic for your desired results is also not clear.  Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT possibles.*, case when st.id is null then 'True' Else 'False' END As IsDeleted
FROM (
    select ids.id, dates.sources_extract_date 
    from 
    (select distinct id from [source_table]) ids
    cross join 
    (select distinct source_extract_date from [source_table]) dates
) possibles
LEFT JOIN [source_table] st ON st.id = possibles.id and st.source_extract_date = possibles.source_extract_date
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work in SQL Server.

```
-- Clear target table
Delete From [Target Table];
GO

-- Add all possible combinations of id & source_extract_date to target table
Insert Into [Target Table] (
            id, 
            source_extract_date, 
            is_deleted
)
Select Distinct
            T1.id, 
            T2.source_extract_date,
            0
From        [Source Table] T1, 
            [Source Table] T2

-- Set is_deleted to true in target table for all possible combinations 
-- of id & source_extract_date which do not exist in source table
Update      [Target Table] 
Set         is_deleted = 1
From        [Target Table] 
Inner Join (
    Select      T1.id, 
                T2.source_extract_date
    From        [Source Table] T1, 
                [Source Table] T2
) [Cartesian Join]
On          [Target Table].Id = [Cartesian Join]
And         [Target Table].source_extract_date = [Cartesian Join].source_extract_date
Where Not Exists(
    Select      1
    From        [Source Table]
    Where       [Source Table].id = [Cartesian Join].Id
    And         [Source Table].source_extract_date = [Cartesian Join].source_extract_date
)
```